# How can I extend a ruby class from a class defined in a module?

Tags: ruby

I have the following files:

> file.rb

```
require_relative 'foo/bar'
baz = Foo::Stuff::Baz.new
# do stuff
```

> foo/bar.rb

```
require_relative 'stuff/baz'
module Foo
    class Bar
        def initialize
            # do stuff
        end
    end
end
```

> foo/stuff/baz.rb

```
module Foo
    module Stuff
        class Baz < Bar
        end
    end
end
```

I get the following error:

> `': uninitialized constant Foo::Stuff::Bar (NameError)

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Is this even possible in Ruby? In case it matters, I'm only doing this because I need to inherit the initialize method specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine when you put them in the same script :

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def initialize
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end

module Foo
  module Stuff
    class Baz < Bar
    end
  end
end

p Foo::Stuff::Baz.ancestors
#=> [Foo::Stuff::Baz, Foo::Bar, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

So it must be a problem with the way or order in which you require your files.

Also, if you just need just one specific method from `Foo::Bar` in `Foo::Stuff::Baz`, you could put this method in a module, and include this module in both classes.

Comment: Yep, you were right. The problem was that I require foo/stuff/baz.rb in foo/bar.rb. I'm marking your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Your `foo/stuff/baz.rb` does not contain any `require` statement and you tell nothing about a main programm. So I think you just don't load the code.

Ruby has no automatic loading depending on folder path, you must explicitly load the source code. In your case you need a `require_relative '../bar'` in the file `foo/stuff/baz.rb`. Then the class `Foo::Bar` is known:

```
require_relative '../bar'

module Foo
    module Stuff
        class Baz < Bar
        end
    end
  end

  p Foo::Stuff::Baz.new
  p Foo::Stuff::Baz.ancestors
```

The result:

```
#<Foo::Stuff::Baz:0x00000002ff3c30>
[Foo::Stuff::Baz, Foo::Bar, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The initialize-method of `Foo::Bar` is executed.

---

A more realistic architecture would be the usage of a main file where you load all code files, e.g.:

```
foo.rb
foo/bar.rb
foo/stuff/baz.rb
```

and foo.rb would contain:

```
require_relative 'foo/bar'
require_relative 'foo/stuff/baz'
```

Comment: I do have the require_relative statements in there, actually. I should have included them in my post.

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaken, I should have the require_relatives for everything in the main file. I'll give that a shot instead.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I realized that the problem is the require statement in my foo/bar.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo::Bar` is defined. You can also access `::Foo::Bar` ("root" module) when there are issues finding the right namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because in baz.rb namespace there is no any reference to the Bar class; should simply enter:

```
class Bar; end
```

So the baz.rb structure becomes simply have:   (foo/stuff/baz.rb)

```
module Foo
  class Bar; end
  module Stuff
    class Baz < Bar
    end
  end
end
```